# How can I keep iTunes meta-information yet replace mp3 with AIFF?

Tags: itunes

I have invested a considerable amount of time to move my music collection from CD to Apple Lossless under iTunes. Earlier on and while short on disk space, I used MPEG encoding for some albums. I would now like to capture again those albums from CD, but in lossless encoding.

Is there any way for me to swipe an album in its previous place, while maintaining all accompanying (meta) information?

Comment: i'm pretty sure the answer is 'no'. The meta data is attached to a file, nothing on the computer is aware that your new file is an equivalent, it's just another file. Unless someone has built an app to do that specific task, then it's a manual copy/paste job, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think that an AAC file could be surreptitiously overwritten with an ALAC (lossless) file as they have the same .m4a extension. But this would not work if the file is MP3. You could try to use iTunes to convert the MP3 file to AAC (.m4a) first, I suppose.